# is it possible to insert new text in the middle of text while it is streaming

Tags: python, asynchronous, websocket, text-to-speech

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import json
import openai
import base64
import shutil
import os
import subprocess

# Define API keys and voice ID
OPENAI_API_KEY = '<OPENAI_API_KEY>'
ELEVENLABS_API_KEY = '<ELEVENLABS_API_KEY>'
VOICE_ID = '21m00Tcm4TlvDq8ikWAM'

# Set OpenAI API key
openai.api_key = OPENAI_API_KEY


def is_installed(lib_name):
    return shutil.which(lib_name) is not None


async def text_chunker(chunks):
    """Split text into chunks, ensuring to not break sentences."""
    splitters = (".", ",", "?", "!", ";", ":", "—", "-", "(", ")", "[", "]", "}", " ")
    buffer = ""

    async for text in chunks:
        if buffer.endswith(splitters):
            yield buffer + " "
            buffer = text
        elif text.startswith(splitters):
            yield buffer + text[0] + " "
            buffer = text[1:]
        else:
            buffer += text

    if buffer:
        yield buffer + " "


async def stream(audio_stream):
    """Stream audio data using mpv player."""
    if not is_installed("mpv"):
        raise ValueError(
            "mpv not found, necessary to stream audio. "
            "Install instructions: https://mpv.io/installation/"
        )

    mpv_process = subprocess.Popen(
        ["mpv", "--no-cache", "--no-terminal", "--", "fd://0"],
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL,
    )

    print("Started streaming audio")
    async for chunk in audio_stream:
        if chunk:
            mpv_process.stdin.write(chunk)
            mpv_process.stdin.flush()

    if mpv_process.stdin:
        mpv_process.stdin.close()
    mpv_process.wait()


async def text_to_speech_input_streaming(voice_id, text_iterator):
    """Send text to ElevenLabs API and stream the returned audio."""
    uri = f"wss://api.elevenlabs.io/v1/text-to-speech/{voice_id}/stream-input?model_id=eleven_monolingual_v1"

    async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
        await websocket.send(json.dumps({
            "text": " ",
            "voice_settings": {"stability": 0.5, "similarity_boost": True},
            "xi_api_key": ELEVENLABS_API_KEY,
        }))

        async def listen():
            """Listen to the websocket for audio data and stream it."""
            while True:
                try:
                    message = await websocket.recv()
                    data = json.loads(message)
                    if data.get("audio"):
                        yield base64.b64decode(data["audio"])
                    elif data.get('isFinal'):
                        break
                except websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosed:
                    print("Connection closed")
                    break

        listen_task = asyncio.create_task(stream(listen()))

        async for text in text_chunker(text_iterator):
            await websocket.send(json.dumps({"text": text, "try_trigger_generation": True}))

        await websocket.send(json.dumps({"text": ""}))

        await listen_task


async def chat_completion(query):
    """Retrieve text from OpenAI and pass it to the text-to-speech function."""
    response = await openai.ChatCompletion.acreate(
        model='gpt-4', messages=[{'role': 'user', 'content': query}],
        temperature=1, stream=True
    )

    async def text_iterator():
        async for chunk in response:
            delta = chunk['choices'][0]["delta"]
            if 'content' in delta:
                yield delta["content"]
            else:
                break

    await text_to_speech_input_streaming(VOICE_ID, text_iterator())


# Main execution
if __name__ == "__main__":
    user_query = "Hello, tell me a very long story."
    asyncio.run(chat_completion(user_query))
```

This is an official example of voice streaming using ElevenLabs and ChatGPT. The text_to_speech_input_streaming function sends the entire text to the ElevenLabs API at once and then starts streaming the generated audio. I want to insert new sentences between the generated ones while the streaming is ongoing. Is it possible to modify the generated text dynamically, and if so, what would be the recommended approach to achieve this?